# How to remove node_modules one folder deep in root

Tags: git, github

I finished step 1 in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@ultravulturekangaroo/fullstack-tddd-mern-crud-app-part-1-af356bf0badb) on how to set up a MERN stack project.

I have a `.gitignore` with the following contents

```
/backend/node_modules
/backend/package-lock.json
```

However, when I `git push`, `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` get added to my respository as seen [here](https://github.com/develijahlee/mern-app)

How can I remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` from my github repository and in future commits?

[image: My project setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a very dumb mistake of setting my git remote add origin in my backend folder and not my root folder. Deleted the project, started again and made sure to to git remote add origin in root and my gitignore behaves as expected.

Comment: I thought it was the case, which is why I mentioned the repository path in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your repository is in the backend folder, meaning you have

```
backend
  .git
```

Then your .gitignore should be:

```
 /node_modules
 /package-lock.json
```

You can:

- `git rm --cached` those two elements
- modify your .gitignore
- add, commit and push

Answer (score 1):

When I compare with my git ignore, there is no / in the beginning of the folder names.
You should look at that. To me it means absolute path.
You should also use git status to check what can be staged before committing anything.
If your node_module is properly ignored by GIT, it will not appear in Git Status.

To remove on Github you should try this

```
git rm --cached node_modules package-lock.json
git commit -m "Your message here."
git push -u origin master
```

Tested this at the moment and it works. my files are still on the local drive but removed from remote repository.
Best Regards.

Comment: I tried removing the forward / from gitignore and tried git rm -r --cached node_modules package-lock.json. The node_modules and package-lock.json go away, but when I try commiting again they appear : /

Comment: I see you seem to have solved your problem.
I work with Visual Studio but sometimes it does not behave as I expected. I definitely prefer working from CLI. I intensively use _git status_ and I could also advise to stop using _git add ._ or _git add -A_ without checking. The doc is available free of charge on the official site  https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2 in many tongues.